# Connecting Shas and Halacha

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, shulchan-aruch

What resources are available to trace the connections from the Gemara to the Halachic codifications and the reverse?  For example, how can someone learning Daf Yomi find the related Halachic rulings in the Shulchan Aruch that were based on that particular page of Talmud, and how would someone studying Mishneh Torah find the source in the Gemara?

Comment: Can you clarify which direction you are looking for (if it matters)? Your question implies a desire to trace Halachah to the Talmud, but your stated goal implies the opposite.

Comment: @SethJ I see your issue, but I think given the answers that are already here that the question should just be [generalized](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1299/759).

Comment: @doubleaa, I find it very confusing.

Comment: @SethJ my *goal* is to flip to the appropriate page(s) in S"A to match up with the daf, but the question is both poorly worded and better off generalized. I hope the edit resolves these issues.

Comment: Actually, maybe that's *too* general.

Comment: @yoel, I think I agree that that may have been too general. How about now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Be'er HaGolah (printed next to the Shulchan Aruch) gives all the sources as listed in Tur/BY. The Biur HaGra gives more thorough sources than the Be'er HaGolah, so you should probably use that one.

There is also, of course, the Ein Mishpat, if you want to go the other way around (Gemara to poskim). It's found at the top of the outer margin of each daf, and it's referenced by k'tav ashurit letters throughout the text of the Gemara.

Comment: Perfect!  Ein Mishpat was what I was thinking of. Thanks!

Comment: I assumed he needed the latter. It'd be kind of tough to go the other direction when you're looking at a piece of Gemara and want to know how we Pasken.

Comment: @SethJ I didn't know which one hae was asking.

Comment: a little biographical information on the Ein Mishpat: http://people.ucalgary.ca/~elsegal/TalmudMap/EMNM.html

Answer (score 9):

If you want to learn the codified halachot that are based on the page of the Talmud you're learning, you should definitely check out the Gemara put out by [The Halacha Brura and Birur Halacha Institute](http://www.halachabrura.org).

An idea from HaRav Kook, see [here](http://www.halachabrura.org/hbabout.htm):

> It was the Rav's desire to publish a new edition of the Talmud, which for the first time, would combine and reunite the study of Halacha and Gemara, which over the years had become two different and independent areas of study...a Talmud which would "return" the basis of Gemara study to the summary of the Halachic conclusions in each and every sugyah, including side discussions which arise in the sugyot.

It is split into two parts, the **Halacha Berura** and the **Biur Halacha**. From [here](http://www.halachabrura.org/idea.htm):

- **Halacha Brura:** This is printed on the Gemara page and was written by Rav Kook himself. The Rav copied the Rambam's and the Shulchan Aruch's Halachic decisions for each topic discussed on that page of the Gemara. This follows the numbering of the Eyn Mishpat.

  Rav Kook also clarifies situations where the Eyn Mishpat is not pointing to the correct place, and sometimes makes notes on what Eyn Mishpat was thinking when pointing to a specific source.
- **Berur Halacha**: Printed in the back of each Gemara, the Berur Halacha summarizes all the different opinions of the Rishonim and Achronim that have impact on the Halachic conclusion of each Sugya, whether they affect the main discussion, or touch only a side point.

The Halacha Berura was done by Rav Kook himself, while the Berur Halacha is done by a committee of Rabbis led by Rav Kook's son (Rav Kook passed away during the editing of the first volume).

Their website has some examples of the Berur Halacha in [the original](http://www.halachabrura.org/dugma.htm) and translated into [English](http://www.halachabrura.org/dugma-e.htm).

I have this Gemara on Berachot and love it. The only possible complaint is that it is not one of the newer prints of the Talmud (only the Rashi is re-typeset). This doesn't bother me for the Gemara itself, but I would prefer the compilation (and retyping) of the Mefarshim found in the back of the Talmud.

---

@ba pointed out in the comments that hebrewbooks.org has the [first Halacha Brura gemara, Beitza](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/40834). The Berur Halacha starts [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40834&pgnum=89).

Comment: Thanks, this looks extremely useful - I'll have to keep an eye out for it.

Comment: See here for how to get a hold of it: http://www.halachabrura.org/public.htm

Comment: By the way, the [volume on Beitzah is online](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/40834)

Answer (score 3):

[b a's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18265) lists the standard short references from *g'mara* to *halacha* and vice versa.

[Menachem's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18267) lists a resource for following a *g'mara* through to its halachic conclusion.

So I'll do the opposite: mention a resource for following a *halacha* back to its talmudic source. The best I've found for this is *Aruch Hashulchan*, who often quotes the relevant *g'mara*, lists how *rishonim* understood it *l'halacha*, often discusses questions on those *rishonim*, and so on, until the final *p'sak*.

Comment: Not the Beit Yosef?

Comment: @DoubleAA, it does the same, but less clearly IME.

Comment: It may not be as accessible but it certainly covers a wider range of opinions and topics.

Comment: Don't forget the Tur, guys.

Comment: I think the question needs to be clarified. His goal seems like this wouldn't help him, even though his question implies that this is what he's looking for.

Comment: @SethJ It's hard to find something in the BY without checking out the Tur :) But seriously, I don't think the Tur really fits the bill. He doesn't have nearly the same depth or breadth that the BY does.

Comment: I love the Tur for his brevity while still bringing in a good deal of source material. You can learn B"Y without Tur if you want to. B"Y is not a supercommentary on the Tur in the sense of the Nosei Keilim on Shu"'A.

Comment: Before you blast me, let me point out that I often learn B"Y to see where Shu"'A is coming from. I learn Tur for the same reason, but it depends on the Se'if whether I learn B"Y, Tur, or both.

Comment: @SethJ Blast for what? I don't think you said anything controversial. But I still don't think the Tur is the work I'd recommend first if someone is hunting upwards in a sugya; he's just not as thorough.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4374/discussion-between-seth-j-and-double-aa)

Answer (score 1):

The new Koren Talmud actually does a very good job at providing not only the Ein Mishpat, but it also gives you the complete Rambam and Shulchan Aruch relevant to particular sugyot.

Comment: This has been in the Oz Vehadar and Vilna Chadash gemaras for years.

Answer (score 0):

For the Mishneh Torah, first look at the commentaries printed in the standard editions. However, the work of these commentaries didn't exhaust all the halachos of the Rambam.  Some of the gaps have been filled in by R' Chaim Kanievsky's in his Kiryat Melech, which fortunately, is available online.