# Best way to learn Hilchos Pesach

Tags: halacha, passover, torah-study, adult-learning

To those with experience, what is the best(very good) way to learn *Hilchos Pesach* . What is a good way to go about it , that will give you a thorough understanding and even *Halacha La'Maaseh*

Comment: one good way is to learn chumash Rashi and Mishnayot Bartenura and Ykar Toyt. before all. but kitsur S.A. is also good, next steps are endless

Comment: Arukh haShulchan is always excellent for his presentation from the original sources to his conclusion. But none of this is specific to Pesach. There are tons of Halachic works out there and most of them cover such a central topic as Pesach. Are you looking for something unique to Pesach, different from how you'd approach any other topic?

Comment: I can't vouch that's it's a *good* way, but one way is to learn through the _Rambam_ (_pesach_ and _chu"m_) and, **for each _halacha_**, investigate upward (to its source) and downward (_Rif_, _Rosh_, _Mord'chay_, etc., _En Mishpat Ner Mitzva_, _Tur_, etc.). Throwing in something like the _Maharil_ will help you pick up some of what you missed along the way.

Comment: I agree with @DoubleAA that "Arukh haShulchan is always excellent for his presentation from the original sources to his conclusion" and might add that _Bes Yosef_ is pretty good at that also.

Comment: If you want a thorough analysis, there are numerous sources, a number mentioned above. If you want a decent quick overview of the important laws from chametz, koshering your home, how to make Seder, etc. the OU guide on the OU kosher site / Pesach division may suffice.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to decide which section of Halachos you want to focus on first and then determine what source(s) to use.  You might not want to learn the intricate Halachos of Kashering dishes and Matzah baking right away whereas the Halachos of the Seder might be more intriguing at first.  Or maybe you want to learn the Halachos of the Korban Pesach or the Tefillos for Pesach?

Comment: I suggest using nitei gavriel  and shmiras hamoadim from harav shimon gadasi.      And  shulchan aruch harav in general you should know that the rav shulchan aruch is an extraordinary shulchan aruch and is worth spending hours daily on every word there is know to have depth of chidushei torah

Comment: @menachem While the Shulchan Arukh haRav is a fine book, unless you are precommitted to following Chabad about everything, I'd strongly recommend against using it as your primary study text. Arukh haShulchan (among other sources suggested above) gives much better background and much more mainstream conclusions which better reflect common practice for the rest of mainstream Ashkenazic Jewry outside the world of Chabad.

Comment: If you don't plan on learning the Tur and Shulchan Aruch,or the Mishnah Brurah  (Aruch Hashulchan ) then I would recommend Rav Shimon Eiders sefer on pesach which I believe is a great resource for what you are describing. http://www.feldheim.com/authors/eider-rabbi-shimon-d/halachos-of-pesach-1-volume-edition.html

Comment: Duplicate? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/39050