# What are the steps to learn via Aliba DaHilchasa?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, torah-study

How does one learn Aliba Dehilchasa? What are the main steps? 
Does it mean to learn the Gemara and then look up the Halacha? Does it mean to Learn a Pasuk then a Gemara then a Halacha? Does it involve Rishonim? I'm here to get educated. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Can you take a look at the suggested duplicate question, and then if your question is different can you [edit] it to explain the difference?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18264/connecting-shas-and-halacha

Comment: Or are you just asking what the definition of Aliba DaHilchaasa is?

Comment: Gemara Rashi tosfot rif Rosh ran tur Bet Yosef, shulchan arurch magen Abraham in of, shach in yd and cm bash in eh and pi tshuva in all is the minimum